# Could not create instance for [Singleton:'androidx.media3.exoplayer.offline.DownloadManager']

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer, koin, download-manager

I'm working on a crash which is tentative. Usually happening on old android device first time installed. Looking for suggestion for fix. Thanks

Below Crash log: